# type 1 generating function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Just found this forum and I have to say you all are doing a great job, keep up!!

The question I want to ask is:

> If I have a canonical transformation like this:
> $$Q=\frac{p}{\cos q},\quad P=-\sin q +\frac{\cos^2\!q}{p^2}$$
> How can I find a type 1 generating function?

Comment: Can you provide some more details or context for the question? Also when typesetting math use `\sin` and `\cos` to distinguish functions from variables. `\cos q` renders as $\cos q$

Comment: Is this question similar to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640549/268448 ?

Comment: Its an exercise from a course I am taking on classical mechanics-Hamiltonian Mechanics, and yes its quite similar the question you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are looking for  generating function $~F(q,Q)$

where:

$$\frac{\partial F(q,Q)}{\partial q}=p\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial F(q,Q)}{\partial Q}=-P\tag 2$$

with:
$$p=Q\,\cos(q)\\
P=-\sin(q)+\frac{\cos^2(q)}{p^2}=-\sin(q)+\frac{1}{Q^2}$$

thus equations (1) and (2)

$${\frac {\partial }{\partial Q}}F \left( q,Q \right) =\sin \left( q
 \right) -\frac{1}{Q^2}\\
{\frac {\partial }{\partial q}}F \left( q,Q \right) =Q\cos \left( q
 \right)
$$

this give you the solution

$$F(q,Q)=Q\,\sin(q)+\frac{1}{Q}$$